# debuggable にビルドするためのチェックポイントは？

Tags: android, gradle

assembleDebug としても debuggalble ビルドが出来なくなりました。確認すべき設定や gradle 項目があれば教えてください。

### 現象の詳細

1. gradle で assembleDebug installDebug する
2. ビルドが成功してアプリがインストールされるので、アプリを起動する。
3. logcatは見えますが、デバッグ可能アプリ一覧に表示されずフィルタが効きません）

### ビルドスクリプト

build.gradle はこんな感じです。

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //keystore はreleaseとdebugで同じものを使っています。
            signingConfig signingConfigs.hoge_keystore
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
```

SDK関連

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
```

### 環境

- Intelli IDEA 14.0.3

Comment: 試してないので、無責任な発言をお許し下さい。apkがパッケージされるために必要な認証鍵=keystoreのデバッグの設定が異なる可能性があります。
AndroidStudioがデバッグ用keystoreとして認識している設定は以下の通りです。File> Project Structure > Facets > Select Packaging Tab(の中の一番最後のオプション "Custom debug keystore")ですね。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-the-debug-keystore-in-android-studio
これが質問者さまのbuild.gradleのsigningConfigsのlivesnap_keystoreエリアのkeystoreと合致しているか、確認してください。リリースと同じものを併用していたりしませんか。そうすると、端末に予めリリース用アプリが入っていてもアップデートで警告が出ず、デバッグ用だとおもってたらリリース用だった。みたいな勘違いが時々あります(個人的に)

Comment: keystore は releaseと同じものをdebugでも使っています。
Project Structure > Facets には、AndroidモジュールとAndroid-Gradle モジュールがあって、Androidモジュールを選択しても詳細ペインが空になります。Android-Gradleモジュールを選択すると、Properties, Signing, Flavors, BuildType, Dependencies タブが表示されますが、それらの中に Custom debug keystore を見つけられませんでした。

Comment: adbの問題である可能性もあるので一度adbのプロセスを全部落としてからIDEAを再起動するといいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

わたしも時々遭遇します(Android Studio 1.0系)

雑な感じになってしまうのですが、PC / Android実機をそれぞれ再起動してみては？

Comment: 直りました。
debuggableかどうかは前々関係なかったのでした。
logcatは流れてきていたので、debuggableかと思い込んでたのですが、デバッグ可能アプリ一覧にアイテムが表示されない時点で、接続がおかしくなってることに気づけば良かった...